# Solving Differential Equation $(1+xy) y + (1-xy) x \frac{\,dy}{\,dx} = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was solving this question on differential equations:

> Solve the differential equation: $$(1+xy) y + (1-xy) x \frac{\,dy}{\,dx} = 0$$

I tried the problem by the following:

$$(1+xy)y\,dx + (1-xy)\,dy=0$$

$$y\,dx+x\,dy = x^2y\,dy - y^2x\,dx$$

$$2\,d(xy) = x^2{\,d \left(\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)}$$

$$2\frac {\,d(xy)}{xy} = \frac{\,d \left(\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{x^2}}}$$

$$2ln(xy) = 2\frac{y}{x} +C$$

$$$$

But the answer given was : $ln \left( \frac{x}{y} \right) - \frac{1}{xy} = C $

I don't see anything I did wrong......

Could anyone share how to do this problem or where I went wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT: I found out what I did wrong thanks to an answer by @J.G. NOw I just wish to know the various methods to this question.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(1+xy) y + (1-xy) x \frac{\,dy}{\,dx} = 0$$
$$(1+xy) ydx + (1-xy) xdy = 0$$
Rearrange terms:
$$dxy+xy^2dx -x^2ydy = 0$$
Divide by $(xy)^2$:
$$\dfrac {dxy}{(xy)^2}+\frac {dx}x -\dfrac {dy}y = 0$$
Integrate:
$$\dfrac 1 {xy}+\ln \bigg|\dfrac yx \bigg|=C$$

Comment: Thanks, that is a really nice method.

Comment: You're welcome. Thank you @SaketGurjar

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is that $x^2d(y^2/x^2)=2x^2ydy-\tfrac{2y^2}{x}dx\ne2x^2ydy-2y^2xdx$.

Note that $xdy=\frac{-y(1+xy)dx}{1-xy}$. Define $w=-\frac{1}{xy},\,u:=we^w$ so $dw=\frac{xdy+ydx}{x^2y^2}=\frac{2dx}{x(xy-1)}$ and $(1+w^{-1})dw=-\frac{2dx}{x}$. So $\frac{du}{u}=(1+w^{-1})dw=-\frac{2dx}{x}$, i.e. $u=cx^{-2}$ for a constant $c$. In terms of the Lambert $W$ function, $y=-\frac{1}{xW(cx^{-2})}$.

Comment: Oh thanks .....